texture from a dynamically generated SVG in pixiJS v8
How can I create a texture from a dynamically generated SVG in pixiJS v8?
This worked in v7:
const testSVG = '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" /></svg>'
, texture = PIXI.Texture.from(testSVG)

but texture logs out as undefined in v8.
And this approach:
  const textureSource = PIXI.TextureSource.from(testsvg )
  const texture = PIXI.Texture.from(textureSource)

Throws this error:
Error: Could not find a source type for resource: <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" /></svg>

Thanks!

I was able to get pixiJS v8 to output an svg with this multi-step process:
const renderer = await PIXI.autoDetectRenderer({
  preference,
  clearBeforeRender: true,
  backgroundAlpha: 0,
  backgroundColor: 0x000000,
  width: 500,
  height: 500
  resolution: 1,
  antialias: false,
  hello: true
});

testsvg = '<SVG viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="red" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" /></SVG>'

const graphics = new PIXI.Graphics().svg(testsvg)
  
, texture = renderer.generateTexture(graphics).

, sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture)

;

I'd still be curious if I'm missing a more straightforward way of outputting an svg in v8, similar to v7's one liner.
